# Write a in c program using loop control to produce the following output

Tags: c

Write a program in c using loop control to produce the following output

```
A B C D E F G
A B C D E F
A B C D E
A B C D
A B C
A B
A
```

i have written this which outouts inverted pyramid using number; but in stand of number i want to output in alphabet shown above please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j, rows;

    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);

    for(i=rows; i>=1; --i)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=i; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ",j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that a homework for us?

Comment: StackOverflow is not for asking people to do your homework. Make an attempt, share your code, and we'll tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: You'll have better luck asking your rubber duck for homework.

Comment: please help me , i tried but cannot do is using alphabate , i can do it using number

Comment: `char c = 'A'; ++c;` What is `c` now?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  We'll help you fix the problems in your honest attempt at writing the code.  We won't just write your program for you.  It looks like two loops nested inside each other.  You've got 3 loop types (`for`, `while`, `do … while`) that you could use.  You could use any of the loop types for the outer loop, and any for the inner loop, so that gives you 9 programs you can write.

Comment: There are two ways of doing this, one standards-compliant and portable and the other using the de-facto [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) character encoding. Using the latter is *very* easy and basically works the same as for your numbers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Even EBCDIC has A-G contiguous (the first break in contiguity is after I).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i can do it using number but cant do it in alphabet

Comment: [Edit] the question to show the code using numbers.

Comment: You briefly posted some code in a comment, but then deleted the comment.  You should edit the code into the question, where you can preserve the formatting.  To post code, enter (preferably copy'n'paste) it into the text box as you want it to look, ignoring the preview, and ensuring you aren't using tabs.  Then select all the code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the code.  Now check the preview to ensure it looks correct.

Comment: Please follow the link in my previous comment, the one [taking you to an ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii). Look at the letters. Look at their values. See some kind of pattern? Then read the comment by @DeiDei. In short, letter are just numbers, and you can do it just the same way as you did for "actual" numbers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why the down vote, is something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Not me who downvoted your answer. But it might be that you just give some code without any kind of explanation of what the OP did wrong. Copy-paste coding is generally looked down upon.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well, thanks for the clarification but i didnt copy paste, just realised with chars will be simple as to the int. will add something then. Thanks

Comment: I didn't mean *you* copy-pasted it, but it's for the OP to copy-paste.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i updated my answer now, i hope is ok. Yea i understand you, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, by simply using char as binary operator and the Increment and Decrement can be applied on chars as well as on integer.
If you want to get input from the user you can use the scanf("%c") to read the chars and use them

```
char i,j;
    for ( i = 'G'; i >= 'A'; i--) { //with G and reduce it by one to get the next ending char
        for (j = 'A'; j <= i; j++) {//start with 'A' to begin every newline
            printf("%c ",j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

> output:

```
A B C D E F G 
A B C D E F 
A B C D E 
A B C D 
A B C 
A B 
A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    const char *A_Z = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int i, j, rows;

    printf("Enter the number of rows(1-26): ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    for(i = rows; i >= 1; --i){
        for(j = 0; j < i; ++j){
            if(j)
                putchar(' ');
            printf("%c", A_Z[j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```